# Create view-only backup and adding digital signature

Tags: windows-10, backup, windows-backup, read-only, digital-signature

I need to create a backup of a computer running Windows 10.

Said backup needs to be read-only.

I believe the program EaseUs allows that. If anyone can confirm, I’d appreciate it. I am used to Linux and MacOS. Have never touched a Windows device and will only have one hour to make the backup.

Also, I want to add a digital signature based on the backup such that any modification to it would break the signature.

Any tips or programs (no matter if paid) are welcome.

Comment: google `forensics software`

Comment: How can a backup be *view-only* if created on writable media? Perhaps a finalized DVD or Blu-ray disk might be considered read-only... but anything created on HDD or SSD can be overwritten.